# Как правильно найти путь к файлу в web-проекте java

Tags: java, java-ee

Работал в Eclipse для Standart Edition, указывал относительный путь и все хорошо было, перешел на  Eclipse для Enterprise Edition, пишу тоже самое, не получается. Решил вывести текущий путь проекта, а мне выдало не путь к моему проекту, а путь где лежит Eclipse, совсем на другом диске моего компа.

Comment: На сколько я понял, когда я запускаю сервер Tomcat, у меня текущая директория становиться этого сервера, как мне сделать так, что бы классы с проекта видели по относительному пути другие файлы в этом проекте, потому что указываю относительный путь к файлу, они думают что находятся возле сервера.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для получения текущего (для вызывающего класса) URL ->

```
String resours = TestClass.class.getResource("").toString();
```

путь к root или любой другой директории либо substring отрежет либо методом обращения к старшей по ирархии директорией ../../

Answer (score 0):

Попрбуйте так:

```
InputStream stream = getClass().getClassloader().getResourceAsStream("./test.txt");
```

для файла с именем `test.txt` лежащего в корне веб приложения